# nolearn/lasagne ImportError: No module named layers

Tags: python, layer, convolution, lasagne, nolearn

I am getting an error when I try to run CNN program [CNN](https://www.kaggle.com/darioxfz/digit-recognizer/digit-recognizer-in-python-using-cnn) using my own data set. Im using `Python2.7`

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lasagne.layers import get_all_layers
ImportError: No module named layers
```

I already upgrade my libraries before,and when I run the main file,I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\mnis2.py", line 78, in <module>
    net1.fit(train, target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne.py", line 140, in fit
    self._print_layer_info(self.get_all_layers())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne.py", line 376, in _print_layer_info
    output_shape = layer.output_shape()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the library installed.

Comment: I've upgraded the library before,but still got error @MartinKonecny

Comment: Have you also tried using the latest development versions of both theano and lasagne?

pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip

(In case you don't have pip you can download and install the packages manually or there are instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)